# Error creating bean, injection of resources failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Main class

```java
public class HealthcareMsDoctorsApplication {
    private HashMap<String, Long> expertises;
    private HashMap<String, Long> languages;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HealthcareMsDoctorsApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean(name = "Experts")
    public HashMap<String, Long> Experts() {
        return this.expertises;
    }

    @Bean(name = "Languages")
    public HashMap<String, Long> Languages() {
        return this.languages;
    }
}
```

Service Layer Class

```java
public class IExpertizeImpl implements IExpertize {
    @Autowired
    @Resource(name="Experts")
    private HashMap<String, Long> Experts;
}
```

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expertiseService':
Error creating bean with name 'IExpertizeImpl':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Experts':
No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Long>' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I created two maps in the Main class marked with `@Bean` and autowired them in the respective Service classes.

Comment: What happens if you use `@Qualifer` insteade of `@Resource`? As basically `@Autowired` and `@Resource` are mutally exclusive.

Comment: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expertiseService': Error creating bean with name 'IExpertizeImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Experts': No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Long>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("Experts")}: it not working

Comment: You are not initializing `expertises` and `languages` maps anywhere.